# Transparent layout in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing one android application which use transparent activity.. I used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) as reference but my problem is when i set background color as black i am not able see previous. i need transparent like this .

[image]

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had requirements to do the same thing in My Application, and I tried the above solution but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

After searching a lot for the same Issue, I have found one another solution That I would like to share here,

I have one `Demo.java` activity for top and `Test.java` Activity to show in background..So for that I have created one **Style and applied to Demo.java** ...and Magic..All Worked.!!

style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.D1NoTitleDim" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and in Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="Demo"
android:theme="@style/Theme.D1NoTitleDim"></activity>
```

Hope This will help Others Too.
Enjoy Coding.!!

And you must make the following changes in the target activity (let's say splash activity):

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {}
```

Be sure to extend it to the activity

Comment: thank you.. i dont need to create the new same question.... :D

this is what I needed....

Comment: thanks this worked like a charm ... but how do you get out from the default color ? Like here for the background you are using @android:color/transparent ... but lets say that I want a purplish background ... how do i get this color ?

Answer (score 34):

Try setting your background color to somewhat transparent, i.e. `#55000000` or '#5000'. Create `colors.xml` in your `res/values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <color name="background">#55000000</color>
</resources>
```

Then use the color in your theme style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <style name="YourTheme" parent="android:@Theme.Translucent">
           <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
     </style>
</resources>
```

Key thing here is to set `Theme.Translucent` as parent of your style, I've tried same with `Theme.Light` and that didn't work.