# Background blur while using dialog box

Tags: android

I want the background behind the dialog box to be blurry. I used this code but it black outs the whole background instead of blur

```
dialog = new Dialog(context,R.style.Theme_Dialog_Translucent);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create `styles.xml` with custom style under `res - values` folder, as [described by Chirag Patel here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8831226/208273):

> ```xml
> <style name="Theme.D1NoTitleDim" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
>     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
>     <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
>     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
>     <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>        
> </style>
> ```

and then use this style with your dialog

```
dialog = new Dialog(context,style);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this instead:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.dimAmount=0.0f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

Comment: still the same ... I guess its because FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND is deprecated .... is there any alternate way?

Comment: Not directly from the SDK, at least that I'm aware of. I suppose you could create a custom background that gives a "blurry" effect and use that.