# blur window when showing AlertDialog in android

Tags: android

I want make background window blur when showing alert dialog.
I have tried -

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
    lp.dimAmount = 0.0f;
    dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

but it is not working in, also it seems "FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND" is deprecated.
is there any other way to achieve this without using third party libraries?

Comment: Check it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632120/background-blur-while-using-dialog-box

Comment: Check out this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21278278/4838244). It just works for me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311192/blur-background-behind-alertdialog--->this makes my app working slow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632120/background-blur-while-using-dialog-box this only gives dim effect not blur effect