# Why the alertbuilder dialog is having extra black color around the corners?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-windowmanager

I'm trying to build the alert dialog box as below dynamically. Everything is working fine.

```
 final Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setView(view);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setOnCancelListener(new SortOnCancelListener(viewable, this));
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());

            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

            lp.width = (int) ((int)displaymetrics.widthPixels * 0.6);
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            dialog.show();
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Except i'm getting the extra black color surrounding across the corners as shown below
[image]

Please let me know where i'm doing wrong.

Thanks,
Sharath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: sure i will check and let you know. Thanks

Comment: backside blur effect is not coming up when dialog is opened. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632120/background-blur-while-using-dialog-box