# different colored transparent android layouts

Tags: android, layout, transparent

So I referred to the following link here : [question on transparent layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285981/transparent-layout-in-android) and I used the answer to get a transparent activity background. But I did realize that the background attribute in the code was generic.

```
<style name="Theme.D1NoTitleDim" parent="android:style/Theme.Translucent">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**How do I achieve a purplish transparent background or any colored background that is transparent ?**  Help Please :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way that works:

In the `layout.xml` file for which you are implementing the above mentioned style, you need to give a background attribute(in the xml file), which in my case was purplish: #972A81. So referring to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285961/how-to-make-a-background-transparent-20-in-android)
I found there, you simple add `CC` to your background declaration which would mean you would get something like this.

```
android:background = "#CC972A81"
```