# Make Layout transparent

Tags: java, android, layout, transparent

Ive got a Layout where I have viewpager with sliding tabs.Now I want to make the upper part of my layout transparent so I get the effect that the activity before it is kinda visible. 
It should look like this :[image]

My Layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Main">            

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp" //THIS part should make the upper piece transparent
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<com.kas.SlidingTabs.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    ></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My Apptheme I used in this Activity :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**I allready** tried `@android:color/transparent` as background in LinearLayout but its not helping.I also tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8831226/4035864

But then my logcat says :`You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

EDIT:
ToolbarLayout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: Do you put the `@android:color/transparent` to your `LinearLayout` and in your `include` ?

Comment: No I tried only in Linear Layout. I dont want to make the toolbar transparent look at the image

Comment: Can we see your include ?

Comment: I did watch out for EDIT section in my first Post

Comment: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme" -- Update your styles.xml with the correct theme, then.

Comment: Also it isn't possible to make "the activity before kinda visible" because Activities aren't just layered on top of one another. Making a transparent Activity won't show the Activity beneath it.

Comment: Are you sure ? Because I think I saw it a couple of time

Comment: You can do that with `fragment`

Comment: So it should be possible right ?