# Transparent bottom sheet layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a transparent bottom sheet layout, that would allow me to see the contents of the view below it. The bottom sheet is working as expected, however when I set the background to either `@null` or `@android:color/transparent`, the layout's view is white, as opposed to transparent. My layout is as follows:

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".core.activities.MainActivity">
    <!-- stuff here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The linear layout with id `bottom_sheet` holds, well, my bottom sheet. The sheet itself is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_placeholder_layout"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/my_background"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/my_progress_bar" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textColor="@color/my_text"
                android:id="@+id/txt_my_info"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textSize="48px" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:id="@+id/txt_my_address"
                android:textColor="@color/my_secondary_text"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_edit_tree_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-62dp"
        android:elevation="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end|right"
        app:useCompatPadding="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is color of    android:background="@color/curio_background" ?

Comment: It's colour is #FFD162 :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent layout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285981/transparent-layout-in-android)

Answer (score 12):

The answer is much more easier: just add this line

`myDialog
.getWindow()
.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);`

And don't change standard ids (R.id.design_bottom_sheet and android.R.color.transparent). It makes background of Bottom Sheet Dialog transparent

Comment: Thank you, but I needed to add decorView to make it work. Kotlin example: `myDialog.window.decorView
                .findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
                .setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent)`

Answer (score 9):

```
private void setupDialogBackground() {
    getDialog().setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (bottomSheet == null)
                return;
            bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            bottomSheet.setBackground(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: works great! The second row from the end can be removed though.

Comment: this working for me! 
bottomSheet.setBackground(null);

Answer (score 8):

add this in styles.xml

```
 <style name="TransparentDialog" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">     @android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimAmount">0.3</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>


   BottomSheetDialog bsDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this,R.style.TransparentDialog);
   bsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottomsheet_dialog);
   bsDialog.show();
```

and voila it works

Answer (score 2):

I had to wait until after setContentView was called in onActivityCreated in order to access the container.  Also while `getDialog().getWindow().findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet)` did successfully find the FrameLayout, I decided to avoid explicitly calling out the internally defined id by using `getView().getParent()`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  // setContentView called here
    ((View) getView().getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your bottomSheet `setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style)`

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

and also add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to root view

Answer (score 1):

Just need to use this style:

```
<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialogThem" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

and set your style to `BaseBottomSheetDialogThem`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the kotlin version thanks to [kolorszczak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40635862/6478047) . Hope it save someones time converting .

```
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(activity!!)
 dialog.setOnShowListener {
            var dialogTmp: BottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
            var bottomSheet: FrameLayout? =
                dialogTmp.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?
                    ?: return@setOnShowListener
            bottomSheet?.background = null
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create in your color.xml : `<color name="colorTransparent">#00000000</color>`
and use `android:background="@color/colorTransparent"`

Comment: That is the same than using `@android:color/transparent`, which doesn't work. `@android:color/transparent` is defined as `<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>`

Comment: use it instead of `android:background="@null"`

Comment: Thanks, however as I was saying in the question, the problem is that this doesn't work :)

Answer (score -1):

change color background

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_placeholder_layout"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Try it!!

Comment: Thanks Nguyễn. I tried it, but unfortunately this doesn't work. The problem persists...