# How to change transparent background in BottomSheetDialog?

Tags: android

I work with BottomSheetDialog, and some difficulties have occurred. I want to remove the background of the black background, and change it to transparency. I tried this [BottomSheetDialog with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104960/bottomsheetdialog-with-transparent-background) , but it did not work out. Help me.

[enter image description here][1]

code is:

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
    View parentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.content_status_dialog,null);
    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(parentView);
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View)parentView.getParent());
    bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(true);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight((int)TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,100,
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

    bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

If I add some style like this

```
 ((View) getView().getParent()).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

, it will look like this

Comment: Have you tried all solutions from attached question?

Comment: use animation from bottom to up with alert box (transparent) ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent bottom sheet layout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37500339/transparent-bottom-sheet-layout-in-android)

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. But they change the background of the dialogue, and I need to change the background over the diolog to transparency.

Comment: @Mukhit just add this bottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0);

before bottomSheetDialog.show();

Comment: @Subzero Thank you bro

Answer (score 6):

The only thing that needs to be done is by adding this line:

```
if(bottomSheetDialog.getWindow() != null)
bottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0);
```

before

```
bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

Comment: seems not working.